# Does the Clone Bay regenerate your crew's health when you "wait" at The Last Stand?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The Clone Bay regenerates your crew's health every time you jump. Does "waiting" at the Last Stand count as a jump?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, waiting counts as a jump and will heal your crew.

Comment: Note that it counts as a jump for Clone Bay but not for everything, for instance, your deployed defense Drones will stay (and attack ones don't)